# Web scraping a specific value returned by a simulator

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

From [this website](https://www.unibanco.pt/solucoes-credito/credito-pessoal/?sum=12.000%20%E2%82%AC&term=54%20meses), I would like to be able to set up the parameters ("Escolha o montante" and "Escolha o prazo") and get the information that is calculated, like "Mensalidade", "TAEG", ...

I have been able to get all the content from json file. But I'm not being able to parse this info and I don't need all the info.

```py
import requests 

url_unibanco = 'https://www.unibanco.pt/credit-simulation/credito-pessoal-novos-clientes/json/'
headers_unibanco = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'} 

response_unibanco = requests.get(url_unibanco, headers=headers_unibanco).json()

print(response_unibanco)
```

This is part of the output, I can't paste everything because it exceeds the limits:

```py
{'matrix_post_id': 135312, 'title': 'Soluções de crédito', 'subtitle': 'Faça já a sua simulação', 'content': '', 'css': 'bg-orange', 'inputs': [{'name': 'sum', 'label': 'Escolha o montante', 'steps': ['5.000 €', '5.500 €', '6.000 €', '6.500 €', '7.000 €', '7.500 €', '8.000 €', '9.000 €', '10.000 €', '11.000 €', '12.000 €', '13.000 €', '14.000 €', '15.000 €', '17.500 €', '20.000 €', '22.500 €', '25.000 €', '27.500 €', '30.000 €', '32.500 €', '35.000 €', '37.500 €', '40.000 €', '42.500 €', '45.000 €', '47.500 €', '50.000 €']}, {'name': 'term', 'label': 'Escolha o prazo', 'steps': ['24 meses', '30 meses', '36 meses', '42 meses', '48 meses', '54 meses', '60 meses', '66 meses', '72 meses', '78 meses', '84 meses', '90 meses', '96 meses', '102 meses', '108 meses', '114 meses', '120 meses']}], 'outputs': [{'name': 'monthly_payment', 'label': 'Mensalidade', 'active': True, 'suffix': '€', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'tan', 'label': 'TAN', 'active': True, 'suffix': '%', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'taeg', 'label': 'TAEG', 'active': True, 'suffix': '%', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'mtic', 'label': 'MTIC', 'active': True, 'suffix': '€', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'protection', 'label': 'Seguro facultativo', 'active': True, 'suffix': '', 'source': 'extra'}], 'values': {'0': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '228,05', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,6', 'mtic': '5.630,83', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '18,21', 'clientcost': '630,83'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '189,50', 'tan': '9,80', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '5.851,95', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '26,35', 'clientcost': '851,95'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '162,52', 'tan': '10,10', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.026,93', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '32,71', 'clientcost': '1.026,93'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '143,27', 'tan': '10,30', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.203,36', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '39,15', 'clientcost': '1.203,36'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '128,90', 'tan': '10,45', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.382,45', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '45,67', 'clientcost': '1.382,45'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '117,86', 'tan': '10,60', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.569,11', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '52,48', 'clientcost': '1.569,11'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '109,03', 'tan': '10,70', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.755,45', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '59,28', 'clientcost': '1.755,45'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '101,89', 'tan': '10,80', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.948,10', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '66,36', 'clientcost': '1.948,10'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '95,89', 'tan': '10,85', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '7.137,30', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '73,23', 'clientcost': '2.137,30'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '90,88', 'tan': '10,90', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '7.330,59', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '80,32', 'clientcost': '2.330,59'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '86,77', 'tan': '11,00', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '7.540,02', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '88,00', 'clientcost': '2.540,02'}}, '1': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '250,86', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '6.190,18', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '20,04', 'clientcost': '690,18'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '208,45', 'tan': '9,80', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '6.432,41', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '28,97', 'clientcost': '932,41'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '178,77', 'tan': '10,10', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '6.624,01', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '36,00', 'clientcost': '1.124,01'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '157,60', 'tan': '10,30', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '6.817,12', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '43,07', 'clientcost': '1.317,12'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '141,79', 'tan': '10,45', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.013,31', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '50,27', 'clientcost': '1.513,31'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '129,65', 'tan': '10,60', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.217,61', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '57,78', 'clientcost': '1.717,61'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '119,93', 'tan': '10,70', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.421,74', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '65,22', 'clientcost': '1.921,74'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '112,08', 'tan': '10,80', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.632,63', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '73,01', 'clientcost': '2.132,63'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '105,48', 'tan': '10,85', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.839,84', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '80,61', 'clientcost': '2.339,84'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '99,97', 'tan': '10,90', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '8.051,55', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '88,43', 'clientcost': '2.551,55'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '95,45', 'tan': '11,00', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '8.280,98', 'sducredit': '132,00', 'sdi': '96,85', 'clientcost': '2.780,98'}}, '2': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '273,66', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '6.749,50', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '21,84', 'clientcost': '749,50'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '227,40', 'tan': '9,80', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.012,94', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '31,62', 'clientcost': '1.012,94'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '195,02', 'tan': '10,10', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.221,12', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '39,27', 'clientcost': '1.221,12'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '171,93', 'tan': '10,30', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.430,87', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '46,99', 'clientcost': '1.430,87'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '154,68', 'tan': '10,45', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.644,03', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '54,81', 'clientcost': '1.644,03'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '141,43', 'tan': '10,60', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '7.866,13', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '63,01', 'clientcost': '1.866,13'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '130,83', 'tan': '10,70', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '8.088,06', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '71,19', 'clientcost': '2.088,06'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '122,27', 'tan': '10,80', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '8.317,10', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '79,63', 'clientcost': '2.317,10'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '115,07', 'tan': '10,85', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '8.542,27', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '87,93', 'clientcost': '2.542,27'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '109,05', 'tan': '10,90', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.772,60', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '96,40', 'clientcost': '2.772,60'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '104,12', 'tan': '11,00', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '9.022,10', 'sducredit': '144,00', 'sdi': '105,65', 'clientcost': '3.022,10'}}, '3': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '296,47', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '7.308,81', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '23,66', 'clientcost': '808,81'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '246,35', 'tan': '9,80', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '7.593,43', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '34,25', 'clientcost': '1.093,43'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '211,27', 'tan': '10,10', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '7.818,23', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '42,54', 'clientcost': '1.318,23'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '186,26', 'tan': '10,30', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.044,65', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '50,89', 'clientcost': '1.544,65'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '167,57', 'tan': '10,45', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.274,80', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '59,38', 'clientcost': '1.774,80'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '153,22', 'tan': '10,60', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.514,60', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '68,23', 'clientcost': '2.014,60'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '141,74', 'tan': '10,70', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.754,07', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '77,09', 'clientcost': '2.254,07'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '132,46', 'tan': '10,80', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.001,65', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '86,29', 'clientcost': '2.501,65'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '124,66', 'tan': '10,85', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.244,83', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '95,29', 'clientcost': '2.744,83'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '118,14', 'tan': '10,90', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.493,44', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '104,43', 'clientcost': '2.993,44'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '112,80', 'tan': '11,00', 'taeg': '13,5', 'mtic': '9.762,96', 'sducredit': '156,00', 'sdi': '114,46', 'clientcost': '3.262,96'}}, '4': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '319,27', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '7.868,20', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '25,51', 'clientcost': '868,20'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '265,30', 'tan': '9,80', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.173,96', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '36,88', 'clientcost': '1.173,96'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '227,53', 'tan': '10,10', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.415,26', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '45,81', 'clientcost': '1.415,26'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '200,59', 'tan': '10,30', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.658,45', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '54,81', 'clientcost': '1.658,45'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '180,47', 'tan': '10,45', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '8.905,42', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '63,95', 'clientcost': '1.905,42'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '165,01', 'tan': '10,60', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.162,97', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '73,44', 'clientcost': '2.162,97'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '152,64', 'tan': '10,70', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.420,32', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '83,03', 'clientcost': '2.420,32'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '142,65', 'tan': '10,80', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.686,16', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '92,92', 'clientcost': '2.686,16'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '134,25', 'tan': '10,85', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '9.947,31', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '102,60', 'clientcost': '2.947,31'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '127,23', 'tan': '10,90', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '10.214,32', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '112,49', 'clientcost': '3.214,32'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '121,48', 'tan': '11,00', 'taeg': '13,4', 'mtic': '10.503,72', 'sducredit': '168,00', 'sdi': '123,26', 'clientcost': '3.503,72'}}, '5': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '342,08', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '8.427,49', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '27,31', 'clientcost': '927,49'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '283,16', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '13,0', 'mtic': '8.721,85', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '38,26', 'clientcost': '1.221,85'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '241,58', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,7', 'mtic': '8.933,13', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '46,06', 'clientcost': '1.433,13'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '211,94', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '9.147,44', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '53,90', 'clientcost': '1.647,44'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '189,78', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '9.364,70', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '61,87', 'clientcost': '1.864,70'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '174,50', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,7', 'mtic': '9.687,60', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '73,98', 'clientcost': '2.187,60'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '160,83', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '9.923,60', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '82,68', 'clientcost': '2.423,60'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '149,69', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '10.163,06', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '91,58', 'clientcost': '2.663,06'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '140,46', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '10.405,55', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '100,50', 'clientcost': '2.905,55'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '132,68', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '10.651,63', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '109,61', 'clientcost': '3.151,63'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '126,06', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '10.900,57', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '118,79', 'clientcost': '3.400,57'}, '11': {'monthly_payment': '120,35', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '11.153,18', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '128,21', 'clientcost': '3.653,18'}, '12': {'monthly_payment': '115,39', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '11.408,56', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '137,60', 'clientcost': '3.908,56'}, '13': {'monthly_payment': '111,05', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '11.667,06', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '147,24', 'clientcost': '4.167,06'}, '14': {'monthly_payment': '107,22', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '11.928,64', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '156,94', 'clientcost': '4.428,64'}, '15': {'monthly_payment': '103,81', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '12.193,79', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '166,71', 'clientcost': '4.693,79'}, '16': {'monthly_payment': '100,78', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '12.461,22', 'sducredit': '180,00', 'sdi': '176,70', 'clientcost': '4.961,22'}}, '6': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '364,89', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '8.986,85', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '29,14', 'clientcost': '986,85'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '302,04', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '13,0', 'mtic': '9.300,17', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '40,82', 'clientcost': '1.300,17'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '257,68', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,6', 'mtic': '9.524,90', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '49,10', 'clientcost': '1.524,90'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '226,07', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '9.752,95', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '57,51', 'clientcost': '1.752,95'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '202,43', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '9.984,02', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '66,02', 'clientcost': '1.984,02'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '186,13', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,6', 'mtic': '10.327,84', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '78,92', 'clientcost': '2.327,84'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '171,55', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '10.579,05', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '88,23', 'clientcost': '2.579,05'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '159,67', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '10.833,76', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '97,66', 'clientcost': '2.833,76'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '149,82', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '11.092,00', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '107,27', 'clientcost': '3.092,00'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '141,53', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '11.353,53', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '116,91', 'clientcost': '3.353,53'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '134,46', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '11.618,74', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '126,74', 'clientcost': '3.618,74'}, '11': {'monthly_payment': '128,38', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '11.887,09', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '136,76', 'clientcost': '3.887,09'}, '12': {'monthly_payment': '123,09', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '12.158,85', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '146,79', 'clientcost': '4.158,85'}, '13': {'monthly_payment': '118,45', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '12.434,40', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '157,07', 'clientcost': '4.434,40'}, '14': {'monthly_payment': '114,36', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '12.713,04', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '167,37', 'clientcost': '4.713,04'}, '15': {'monthly_payment': '110,73', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '12.995,00', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '177,92', 'clientcost': '4.995,00'}, '16': {'monthly_payment': '107,50', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '11,9', 'mtic': '13.279,30', 'sducredit': '192,00', 'sdi': '188,46', 'clientcost': '5.279,30'}}, '7': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '410,50', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '10.105,51', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '32,78', 'clientcost': '1.105,51'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '339,80', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,9', 'mtic': '10.456,85', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '45,94', 'clientcost': '1.456,85'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '289,89', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,6', 'mtic': '10.708,51', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '55,23', 'clientcost': '1.708,51'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '254,33', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '10.963,80', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '64,71', 'clientcost': '1.963,80'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '227,74', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '11.222,65', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '74,29', 'clientcost': '2.222,65'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '209,40', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,6', 'mtic': '11.608,32', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '88,79', 'clientcost': '2.608,32'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '192,99', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '11.889,67', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '99,18', 'clientcost': '2.889,67'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '179,63', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '12.175,05', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '109,84', 'clientcost': '3.175,05'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '168,55', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '12.464,28', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '120,61', 'clientcost': '3.464,28'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '159,22', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '12.757,58', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '131,58', 'clientcost': '3.757,58'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '151,27', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '13.054,62', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '142,62', 'clientcost': '4.054,62'}, '11': {'monthly_payment': '144,43', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '13.355,30', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '153,84', 'clientcost': '4.355,30'}, '12': {'monthly_payment': '138,47', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '13.660,47', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '165,23', 'clientcost': '4.660,47'}, '13': {'monthly_payment': '133,26', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '13.968,56', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '176,68', 'clientcost': '4.968,56'}, '14': {'monthly_payment': '128,66', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,0', 'mtic': '14.280,75', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '188,27', 'clientcost': '5.280,75'}, '15': {'monthly_payment': '124,58', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '11,9', 'mtic': '14.596,53', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '200,10', 'clientcost': '5.596,53'}, '16': {'monthly_payment': '120,93', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '11,9', 'mtic': '14.916,54', 'sducredit': '216,00', 'sdi': '212,06', 'clientcost': '5.916,54'}}, '8': {'0': {'monthly_payment': '456,11', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '11.224,20', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '36,42', 'clientcost': '1.224,20'}, '1': {'monthly_payment': '377,55', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,9', 'mtic': '11.613,53', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '51,02', 'clientcost': '1.613,53'}, '2': {'monthly_payment': '322,10', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '11.892,12', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '61,36', 'clientcost': '1.892,12'}, '3': {'monthly_payment': '282,59', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '12.174,75', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '71,89', 'clientcost': '2.174,75'}, '4': {'monthly_payment': '253,04', 'tan': '9,50', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '12.461,41', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '82,58', 'clientcost': '2.461,41'}, '5': {'monthly_payment': '232,67', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,5', 'mtic': '12.888,60', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '98,63', 'clientcost': '2.888,60'}, '6': {'monthly_payment': '214,44', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,4', 'mtic': '13.200,32', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '110,28', 'clientcost': '3.200,32'}, '7': {'monthly_payment': '199,59', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,3', 'mtic': '13.516,33', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '122,04', 'clientcost': '3.516,33'}, '8': {'monthly_payment': '187,28', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '13.836,61', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '133,97', 'clientcost': '3.836,61'}, '9': {'monthly_payment': '176,91', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,2', 'mtic': '14.161,53', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '146,13', 'clientcost': '4.161,53'}, '10': {'monthly_payment': '168,08', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '14.490,49', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '158,47', 'clientcost': '4.490,49'}, '11': {'monthly_payment': '160,47', 'tan': '10,00', 'taeg': '12,1', 'mtic': '14.823,85', 'sducredit': '240,00', 'sdi': '170,91', 'clientcost': '4.823,85'}....
```

For example, if the parameters were:

```
Escolha o montante = 12000€
Escolha o prazo = 54 meses
```

Then the output that I want to get is:

```
Mensalidade = 279,20€
TAEG = 12.5%
```

Comment: Can you add to your question what you get back from `json` and then we can help you with how to process that `json` properly.  In generaly, `json` is a `list` of `dictionaries` or `lists`.  You can access each element either by `key` or by `index`.  Try doing a `type(x)` for each layer to determine what it is and then you can see how to access the parts of it you want.

Comment: as @MyNameIsCaleb said you have python's dictionary with lists and/or subdictionaries. You can use key or index like `response_unibanco['outputs'][0]['label']` - it gives `"Mensalidade"`

Comment: thank you for your replies. The problem is that the json structure in this case is complex, and using indexes that are linked to the sliders instead of keys. So, do you think it would be possible to extract only the information that I need instead of extract everything and then parse the information?

Comment: It would be best to add the json response to your question and then we could help you with that.  Most people answering questions are not going to do a web scrape locally to answer for you, you should provide all of the data needed to answer in your question instead.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I've paste part of the outcome, thanks a lot

Comment: @brunosm I put an answer below that should get you to where you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all of the combinations are being provided in a nested dictionary based on the "step" of the parameters available to be chosen.

First in your output you have the parameter options which you will need to search to find out the step you need.  Step `0` will be `'5.000 €'` for `'Escolha o montante'`

```
{'matrix_post_id': 135312, 
 'title': 'Soluções de crédito', 
 'subtitle': 'Faça já a sua simulação', 
 'content': '', 'css': 'bg-orange', 
 'inputs': [
     {'name': 'sum', 
      'label': 'Escolha o montante', 
      'steps': ['5.000 €', '5.500 €', '6.000 €', '6.500 €', '7.000 €', '7.500 €', '8.000 €', '9.000 €', '10.000 €', '11.000 €', '12.000 €', '13.000 €', '14.000 €', '15.000 €', '17.500 €', '20.000 €', '22.500 €', '25.000 €', '27.500 €', '30.000 €', '32.500 €', '35.000 €', '37.500 €', '40.000 €', '42.500 €', '45.000 €', '47.500 €', '50.000 €']},
     {'name': 'term', 
      'label': 'Escolha o prazo', 
      'steps': ['24 meses', '30 meses', '36 meses', '42 meses', '48 meses', '54 meses', '60 meses', '66 meses', '72 meses', '78 meses', '84 meses', '90 meses', '96 meses', '102 meses', '108 meses', '114 meses', '120 meses']}],
```

Then you have some stuff you can probably ignore:

```
'outputs': [{'name': 'monthly_payment', 'label': 'Mensalidade', 'active': True, 'suffix': '€', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'tan', 'label': 'TAN', 'active': True, 'suffix': '%', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'taeg', 'label': 'TAEG', 'active': True, 'suffix': '%', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'mtic', 'label': 'MTIC', 'active': True, 'suffix': '€', 'source': 'values'}, {'name': 'protection', 'label': 'Seguro facultativo', 'active': True, 'suffix': '', 'source': 'extra'}],
```

And finally you have your big list of options, this is separated by first dictionary being the step for `Escolha o montante` and then nested inside of that is the dictionary for `Escolha o prazo`.  You would need to know the steps you need for each and then just access them as keys `[montante_step][prazo_step]`

```
'values': {'0':    # Escolha o montante step here, prazo next
    {'0':   {'monthly_payment': '228,05', 'tan': '8,50', 'taeg': '12,6', 'mtic': '5.630,83', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '18,21', 'clientcost': '630,83'}, 
     '1': {'monthly_payment': '189,50', 'tan': '9,80', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '5.851,95', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '26,35', 'clientcost': '851,95'}, 
     '2': {'monthly_payment': '162,52', 'tan': '10,10', 'taeg': '13,6', 'mtic': '6.026,93', 'sducredit': '120,00', 'sdi': '32,71', 'clientcost': '1.026,93'}, ...
```

So in the end you would need to access those based on the step you need.  Let's say you need step 2, 5:

```py
print(response_unibanco['values'][2][5])
```

To make the steps accessible you probably should convert them into a dictionary up front:

```py
montante_steps = response_unibanco['inputs'][0]['steps']
montante_step_lookup = {montante_steps[y]:y for y in range(0, len(montante_steps))}
```

Now you can lookup one of the steps by value such as `montante_step_lookup['5.000 €']` which will return `0`.

Comment: @brunosm No problem.